# Format of result TSP at OSM2PO?

Tags: osm2po

I use JavaScript to work with the program OSM2PO. I want to solve the problem of TSP. I need to get the order Vertex Ids and array waypoints in one query. Is it possible in the format Json? It would also be good to get the distance and time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but an all-in-one result is not part of the current rest-api. Nevertheless, with few lines of Java code, it is possible to create what you want.